# Play application, how to reuse configurations in sub-projects?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

My Play application defines some project level configurations at the project root:

`/project/conf/resources.conf`

And I define some sub-project configurations:

`/project/modules/my_sub_project/conf/application.conf`

application.conf includes the parent resources with:

`include "resources"`

When I run my sub_project with:

`/project$ sbt run my_sub_project`

And retrieve configurations with:

`Play.application().configuration()`

The configurations from `application.conf` are loaded, but those in `resources.conf` are not.

I have also tried the below include statements, but they have same result:

`include "resources.conf"
include "../../../resources.conf"
include "../../resources.conf"`

Any suggestion on how I should troubleshoot the project level configurations not loading? Any suggestions on how I should setup my project such that my sub-project can inherit configurations?

Comment: I'm not sur that it is possible. You can still share a module containing only a resources.conf file